# Почему не открываются сайты QWebEngine?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qwebengineview

Пишу браузер.  Создаю экземпляр класса **`QWebEngineView`**. 
Задаю ему `url` по умолчанию: "https://www.google.ru/search?q=Телепузик", с первого взгляда все работает: поисковая строка, можно в ней писать новые запросы.

*Но почему я не могу ни на сайт зайти, ни видео запустить, ни фото посмотреть?*

P.S. Только не говорите, что этого нельзя осуществить:(

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(1200,1200)

        self.str = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)

        self.str.resize(self.size())
        self.str.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.ru/search?q=Телепузик"))
        
        self.str.urlChanged.connect(self.urll)

    def urll(self):

        self.label.setText(f"{self.str.url()}") #Для проверки того, что url действительно меняется
        print(self.label.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: если вопрос задан с целью получить сочувствие, то сочувствуем. если нужна помощь, приводят код (желательно минимально воспроизводимый)

Comment: Секунду... чутка сокращу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#                                                  vv
#        self.view.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.ru/search?q=Телепузик"))

#                                                 vvv    
#+        self.view.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=Телепузик"))
#+ или так
        self.view.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=Телепузик"))
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(900, 600)

        self.view = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)

#        self.view.resize(self.size())
#        self.view.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.ru/search?q=Телепузик"))

#+        self.view.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=Телепузик"))
        self.view.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=Телепузик"))
        
        self.view.urlChanged.connect(self.urll)
        
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, 0)
        

    def urll(self):
        # Для проверки того, что url действительно меняется
        self.label.setText(f"{self.view.url()}") 
        print(self.label.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все работает как по волшебству! Спасибо! Уже считаю вас своим сенсэем))

Comment: @Bitchdragon пожалуйста.